# how to query many-to-many relationship in same table by redbeanphp?

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have a table named "user" and this table has many to many relation over its own such as favorite action. this means a user can favorite multiple users and can be Favorited by multiple users.

now I want query over this relation and get every users those Favorite a spacial user.

I use this code :

```
$users = $agent->via($TB_Favorite,"agent_id=? and favorite.action=?", array($userId,FAVORITE_TYPE_USER_FAVORITE))->sharedUsers ;
```

I debug this code by profiling database and get this result:

```
        SELECT
            `users`.*  ,
            COALESCE(
            NULLIF(`favorite`.`users_id`, `users`.id),
            NULLIF(`favorite`.`users2_id`, `users`.id)) AS linked_by
        FROM `favorite`
        INNER JOIN `users` ON
        ( `users`.id = `favorite`.`users2_id` AND `favorite`.`users_id` IN ('13') ) OR
        ( `users`.id = `favorite`.`users_id` AND `favorite`.`users2_id` IN ('13') )
```

but in this case it must use **favorite.agent_id** instead **favorite.users2_id** how can i resolve this problem ?

this is my table diagram : 
[image]

may be this make my position clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, thanks for the diagram and the additional explanation.
So, you want to query the users associated with the favorite activities of a user. Here's one possible solution (tested on an empty db here):

```
$x = R::dispense(array(
'_type' => 'user',
'name' => 'Q',
'ownActivity' => array(
    array('_type'=>'favorite', 
         'name'=>'A', 
         'agent'=> array(
              '_type'=>'user', 
              'name'=>'X')),
    array('_type'=>'favorite', 
          'name'=>'B', 
          'agent'=> array(
              '_type'=>'user', 
              'name'=>'Y')),)));
R::store($x);
$me = R::findOne('user', ' `name` = ? ', array('Q'));
$favoriteActivities = $me->ownFavoriteList;
foreach($favoriteActivities as $activity) {
    $agent = $activity->fetchAs('user')->agent;
    $favoriteUsers[$agent->id] = $agent;
    echo $agent->name;
}
```

Comment: this code is awesome...... but you are GOD of redbeanphp .... and you know about  all detail of this library. we are poor :) how we can help you to create a good documentation? i think when redbeanphp has a good documentation it will be most popular ORM of php.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly what you mean, but maybe the aggr feature can be of any help?

http://www.redbeanphp.com/other_relations#aggr

Comment: I need to get users witch add `fav` tag to a spacial user in my 'favorite' table witch has two foreign key with 'user' table

Comment: I searched and find that redbeanphp has many-to-many self-referential support but i want to know why redbean assume users2_id as a column ... and how change it to agent_id